# Is there a way to configure Google Scholar to only show results where the document is freely available?

Tags: google-scholar

When I do a search, many of the papers are only available to subscribers of a particular service, listed as for sale, or behind some other kind of pay wall. However, if a document is available, there's often a link next to the paper title to view the PDF, HTML, or some other format that isn't behind a pay wall.

Is there a way to only show these documents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't an option to restrict results like that in Google Scholar (I appreciate the idea, running into paywalls is very frustrating). I guess the argument could be made that you are limiting the articles/knowledge you could be exposed to be only looking at the free things. That and Google's recognition of what is accessible isn't 100%.

That said, some other ideas:

- **All Versions** - Hit the "All X versions" link, occasionally an alternate site will have a viewable version - or at least show more of the article than the first linked site does.
- **Use the `site:` parameter** - If you do find a some sites that are more generous about freely hosting full articles, just search them for your subject matter with `site:domain.com`
- **Library Links** - A newer feature in Google Scholar is [Library Links](http://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/librarylinks.html). It hooks into libraries you might have access to so you can access articles via them directly from Google. You just need to set what libraries you are a member of in [Scholar Preferences](http://scholar.google.com/scholar_preferences). Obviously this works best if you are a uni student/staff member, but it looks like they are incorporating public libraries as well.